# Removing access to plugin from WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress, function

I am trying to hide plugin "qi-addons-for-elementor/class-qiaddonsforelementor.php" from the admin menu so no one can modify it.

I tried adding the following code to my theme's functions.php but it does not work, please help.

```
function hide_plugins_from_menu() {
    global $submenu;

    // Plugins to hide (adjust the plugin file names as needed)
    $plugins_to_hide = array(
        'qi-addons-for-elementor/class-qiaddonsforelementor.php',
    );

    // Remove the plugins from the admin menu
    foreach ( $plugins_to_hide as $plugin ) {
        if ( isset( $submenu['plugins.php'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $submenu['plugins.php'] as $index => $menu_item ) {
                if ( $plugin == $menu_item[2] ) {
                    unset( $submenu['plugins.php'][ $index ] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_plugins_from_menu' );
```

Comment: Try `admin_init` instead of `admin_menu`

Comment: Also, try adding a priority as the third parameter to `add_action`. The default is `10`, maybe try `20`.

Comment: Thanks, admin_init - did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, I have a code snippet. Might be helpful to you.

```
function remove_menu() {

  global $user;

  if ( $user != 1 ) { //your user id

   remove_menu_page('edit.php'); 
   remove_menu_page('upload.php');
   remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
   remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
   remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
   remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
   remove_menu_page('themes.php');
   remove_menu_page('users.php');
   remove_menu_page('tools.php');
   remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menu' );
```

I copied it from stackoverflow. Currently, I do not have reference details. But it works 100%.